# Running an executable inside a docker container from another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run an executable file from another docker container while already inside a docker container. Is this possible?

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  py:
    build: .
    tty: true
    networks:
      - dataload
    volumes:
      - './src:/app'
      - '~/.ssh:/ssh'

  winexe:
    build: 
      context: ./winexe
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - dataload
    ports: 
      - '8001:8001'
    volumes:
      - '~/path/to/winexe:/usr/bin/winexe'
      - '~/.ssh:/ssh'
    depends_on:
      - py

networks:
  dataload:
    driver: bridge
```

I am trying to access Winexe from 'py'

Comment: This question is very very broad. There are plenty of ways to do this, depending on how you've structured your containers. For example – if both containers are linked by docker-compose, you could have one call to another through its internal url (and appropriate forwarded ports).

Comment: @MichaelBeeson Hi Michael, how would i go about doing this? I edited my post with my docker-compose file.

Comment: What does "trying to access" mean? Do you want to run the executable? Make a network connection to it? Set up a pipe to its stdin or stdout?

Comment: @GercoDries So from my python container, i have a python script that utlizes "winexe.exe" which I've mounted in another container basically.

Comment: `winexe`? You need to clear if it's really mean this is a windows exe or just a name has no relationship with windows! Basically, how do you think you can mount a exe to linux container (As you used `/usr/bin/winexe`), and run it? Use wine? Also, what's your environment, docker for windows or linux? Linux container or windows container? Your question really confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean running another Docker container from inside a container, this can be done in several ways:

Install the `docker` command inside your container and:

1. Contact the hosting Docker instance over TCP/IP. For this you will have to have exposed the Docker host to the network, which is neither default nor recommended.
2. Map the docker socket (usually /var/run/docker.sock) in to your container using a volume. This will allow the `docker` command inside the container to contact the host instance directly.

Be aware this essentially gives the container `root` level access to the host! I'm sure there are many more ways to do the same, but approach number 2 is the one I see most often.

If you mean to run another executable inside another - already running - Docker container, you can do that in the above way as well by using `docker exec` or run some kind of daemon in the second container that accepts commands and runs the required command for you.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to think of your containers as if they were two separate computers, or servers, and they can interact accordingly.

Happily, docker-compose gives you a url you can use to communicate between the containers. In the case of your docker-compose file, you could access the winexe container from your py container like so:

```
http://winexe:8001 // or ws://winexe:8001 or postgres://winexe:8001 (you get the idea)
```

(I've used port 8001 here because that's the port you've made available for winexe – I have no idea if it could be used for this).

So now what you need is something in your winexe container than listens to that signal and sends a useful reply (like a browser sending an ajax call to a server)

Learn more here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/